# route planning with walking sections

Tags: google-maps, graph, routes, neo4j, dijkstra

I am developing an application that can show the shortest route using public transport methods (currently only buses). It should include the sections where one can walk some distance to the next stop rather than taking another bus (if its more shorter).

1. What should be the data structure for the map? I thought of graphical structure with nodes for bus stops. and vertices with distance as weight.
2. Even if I have found the shortest path using an algorithm (dijkstra) how to implement that walking sections in to the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a lot of extra information, it's difficult to give you a great answer to this question, but let me hit some basics.  This should be enough to get you going, but then you're going to need to do additional work to develop your solution.

1. In general, your data structure is going to be something like nodes that represent destinations or waypoints (like a bus stop, or an address).  Your relationships will be modes of transportation with associated costs.  For example, you can get from point/node A to point/node B via walking, or the bus.  Those are two different relationships, with different "costs" in terms of time and money.
2. In general, you'll want to use a "weighted shortest path" algorithm to find the best way from point A to point B.  Neo4j gives you a shortest path function, but in your case you'll need to assign weights to  your relationships, and then calculate the shortest path not based on the number of "hops" through the graph, but based on some overall cost metric (time, money, whatever).

[Ian Robinson wrote a great post on how to do weighted shortest paths in neo4j](http://iansrobinson.com/2013/06/24/cypher-calculating-shortest-weighted-path/).  So you should follow a template like that as a starting point.

You have a bunch of design questions to answer though.  Do you want the shortest path in terms of time, money, effort, or some combination?  The answer to that will affect your graph design, and your query strategy.

Comment: thanx for your idea. Now I have something to work with.